# Storing multiple values in cookies in Java

Tags: java, cookies

I see many solutions for storing multiple values in one cookie in .Net and php but I have not found any good solution for Java. I dont wanna encode/decode the pair-values myself which can be risky.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies values are Strings.

If you want to put structured data in them, you have to make that data a String.

Of course you want that clients can read theses values easily. Query String encoded parameters or JSON seems like good choices as they are browser-native. A JavaScript app could deserialize the structured data in a snap.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to save a unique ID in the cookie (just a long number) and use a synchronized map in your code which gives you some data structure per ID (often another map).

Comment: This sounds to complicated and needs some strategy when restaring the java. I just want to save a couple of name/vaule pairs.

Comment: This is usually handled by your app server. For anything that supports servlets, just use `getSession()` to get access to such a map.

Comment: Thx man! I thought I had to use the Cookies class, but this seems to be just what I need :) I will try it out now!

Answer (score 0):

[HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) has support for [cookies](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/Cookie.html).

Comment: As you asked for help in encode/decode, this library helps to stay in tune with the specifications. See org.apache.commons.httpclient.cookie.CookieSpecBase
, Cookie.toExternalForm(), etc . This is not server/client specific.